# Group regex with fix part

Tags: php, regex, expression

```
$txt = "toto1 555.4545.555.999.7465.432.674";
$rgx = "/([\w]+)\s([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/";
preg_match($rgx, $txt, $res);
var_dump($res);
```

I would like to simplify this pattern by avoiding repeating "([0-9]+)" because i don't know how many they are.

Any one can say me how ?

Comment: Do you need the captured texts? What output do you need?

Comment: Yes i need to capture the same text that in my example :

toto1  
555  
4545  
555  
999  
7465  
432  
674

Comment: Then it is only possible to use *blocks* and build the regex dynamically. There is no other option. You cannot avoid repeating these capturing groups. You might get those substrings with several *matches* though if you use a `\G` based regex.

Comment: Maybe this is simpler https://eval.in/632471

Comment: Yeah, something like a 2-step approach, or [`([\w]+|(?!\A)\G)[\s.]([0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nD8aC7/1) with `preg_match_all`. The output array will be a "bit" messy though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct answer to the question, as you have stated it:

```
/[\w]+\s[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+/
```

**However**, note that I have removed all of the numbered capture groups. This could be problematic, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve.

It is not possible to "count" with capture groups in regular expressions, so you would need to write some other code (i.e. not just one match, with one regex, and using back-references) to deal with this if you wish to run any queries like "What digits appear after the fifth `"."`?"

Comment: Actually, there were no *named capture groups*, just *numbered* ones. And OP stated that the captures should stay. So, this  is not that helpful. Try with `\G`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this. If you just need to verify that the string matches the pattern, this regex will do the job: `\w+\s(?:[0-9]+\.?)+`

However, if you need to split the string in to it's component parts (in my interpretation, the beginning word followed by the sequence of decimal separated numbers), then you could use this pattern: `(\w+)\s((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)`

The second pattern will return the beginning word, `toto1` in group 1, followed by the decimal separated numbers in group 2 `555.4545.555.999.7465.432.674` which you could then split in PHP if required: `$sequence = explode('.', $matches[2]);`

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be obtained with a `preg_split` with a regex matching 1 or more whitespaces or dots:

```
$txt = "toto1 555.4545.555.999.7465.432.674";
$rgx = '/[\s.]+/';
$res = preg_split($rgx, $txt);
print_r($res);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/gpyam0)

If you need a regex approach, you can use a `\G` based regex with `preg_match_all`:

```
'~(?|([\w]+)|(?!\A)\G[\s.]*([0-9]+))~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rL2hX6/1) and a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/eUTJfv):

```
$txt = "toto1 555.4545.555.999.7465.432.674";
$rgx = '~(?|(\w+)|(?!\A)\G[\s.]*([0-9]+))~'; 
preg_match_all($rgx, $txt, $res);
print_r($res[1]);
```

**Pattern details**:

- The `(?|...)` is a branch reset group to reset group IDs in all the branches
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 matches 1+ word chars
- `|` - or (then goes Branch 2)
- `(?!\A)\G` - the end of the previous successful match
- `[\s.]*` - zero or more whitespaces or dots
- `([0-9]+)`  - Group 1 (again!) matching 1 or more digits.